# How to remove microsoft (work) account on Windows 10 when I have no longer access to it?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

In my home PC I have my personal microsoft account and the old work account. The work account is residual - I do not work at the company anymore and the account does not exist. I wanted to remove it, cause notifications about fixing it pop-up constantly. However, it seems like the only way to remove it is by clicking on "manage". Nevertheless, that asks me to log into the account - that is not possible anymore. The account does not exist and the company will, obviously, not provide me an access to it or create it for me again, just so I can remove it on my PC.

Is there any other way how to get rid of it?
[image]

Comment: There should be an "access work or school" page where you can click disconnect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the left pane, choose `access work or school` select your account in the list and then click disconnect. Follow the prompts to complete...

Comment: I really could have seen this. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to create a new computer account, transfer everything to the new account and then delete the old account - Or reinstall WINDOWS 10 after backup!