# Two Microsoft accounts with same email - how to delete the non-personal one?

Tags: user-accounts, microsoft-account

When I enter my email address to log in to https://outlook.live.com, a dialog is shown that says:

> It looks like this email is used with more than one account from Microsoft. Which one do you want to use?
>
> - Work or school account
>   <sup>Created by your IT department</sup>
> - Personal account
>   <sup>Created by you</sup>
>
> Tired of seeing this? [Rename your personal Microsoft account](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=733247).

[image: Dialog asking whether I want to log in to the work or school account or the personal account]

The problem is that there should only be a personal account for that address because it's my non-work email.

Microsoft's advice, as linked in the dialog, seems to be to change the email address of the personal account. However, I don't want to do that; I want to get rid of the "work or school" account.

I guess that one of my previous employers or customers created that account some time ago. In any case, it is no longer functional: Selecting the "work or school" account redirects to https://outlook.office365.com/mail/, but then shows an error page that includes the code `UserHasNoMailboxAndNoLicenseAssignedError`.

How do I get rid of the "work or school" account?

- I can't follow the instructions from the answer to [How to remove microsoft (work) account on Windows 10 when I have no longer access to it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1376665/how-to-remove-microsoft-work-account-on-windows-10-when-i-have-no-longer-acces) because no Windows installation exists that is connected to the "work or school" account. Also, even if I could, the account would still exist afterwards, and various web apps such as https://outlook.live.com would still ask about it during login.
- I can't log into the "work or school" account on https://account.microsoft.com/ because it doesn't give me the choice of "personal" vs. "work or school", it just asks for the password. I encounter the same problem when I follow the instructions given in [How to close your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/home/contact?linkquery=Learn%20about%20closing%20a%20microsoft%20account).
- The instructions linked in the answer to [Delete "work or school" account from a Microsoft account?](https://superuser.com/questions/1548047/delete-work-or-school-account-from-a-microsoft-account) also don't work for me: with a fresh browser context without any cookies, I tried logging in to https://www.office.com/, hoping to force Microsoft to let me into the "work or school" account. The password recovery process asked for the account type, I chose "work or school" and entered my email address. But it claims that (at least for Office) no such account exists! (But if no such account exists, why do I get the login choice dialog?) By the way, the same thing happens when starting over (again without cookies) at https://azure.microsoft.com/.  [image: Password recovery form with an error message saying "The email or usemame you entered does not exist. Please check that you have typed your email or username correctly."]
- I can't contact an "IT department" as it's not clear which company created the account; also, that company may not even exist anymore.

Comment: @Toto, this is not about Windows at all. It's about two accounts in Microsoft's cloud systems.

Comment: This could be on-topic over at [webapps.se], but is off-topic here because it's about an online service.